# MongoDB Aggregate Query in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm attempting to convert my MongoDB aggregate query:

```
db.identification.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userId: "b0e644d2-5a0c-4048-abea-6ae17c337e57"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            status: {
                $objectToArray: "$status"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            status: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$status.k", 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$status",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            status: {
                "name": "$_id",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "counts",
            counts: {$addToSet: "$status"}
        }
    }
])
```

Into the Scala DSL:

```
collection.aggregate(List(
      filter(Document("userId" -> userId)),
      project(Document("status" -> Document("$objectToArray" -> "$status"))),
      project(Document("status" -> Document("$arrayElemAt" -> List("$status.k" -> 0)))),
      group("$status", sum("count", 1)),
      project(Document("_id" -> 0, "status" -> Document("name" -> "$_id", "count" -> "$count"))),
      group("counts", addToSet("counts", "$status"))
    ))
```

However, when I attempt to run the query I get the following error:

`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 168: 'Unrecognized expression '$status.k'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$status.k'", "code" : 168, "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator" }`

Is there a way to use a pre-defined aggregate query, or can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `List("$status.k",  0)`

Comment: @Veeram, no, the list is expected to be of tuples.

Comment: @Veeram, you make a good point, but I'm not sure what to change it to. If I just make it a `List("$status.k", 0)` it won't compile.

Comment: So this doesn't compile `project(Document("status" -> Document("$arrayElemAt" -> List("$status.k", 0))))` ?

Comment: @Veeram, no, I get: `[error]  cannot be applied to ((String, List[Any]))
[error]       project(Document("status" -> Document("$arrayElemAt" -> List("$status.k", 0)))),`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this can be worked around with the following:

```
project(Document("status" -> Document("$arrayElemAt" -> List(BsonString("$status.k"), BsonInt32(0)))))
```

I'll hold out for hopefully a cleaner solution. It looks as though the implicit conversions can't properly handle `Int`.